# Arduino Port Not detected and can not run it as root

Tags: usb, permissions, serial-port, arduino

I have two Ubuntu one is 18.04 and another is 20.04, also i have some problem with Arduino boards,i have tried [this](https://idyl.io/arduino/how-to/program-stm32-blue-pill-stm32f103c8t6/) instruction(pin connections and ...):
[image]

But, the Arduino IDE can not detect the STM32f013c8t6 board with Arduino, so i tried to find the USB connection of the port by using [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1261380/error-in-recognizing-arduino-on-ubuntu-20-04) post commands of its answers, as you can see below:

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER
 ls -al /dev/USB*
ls: cannot access '/dev/USB*': No such file or directory
```

And by trying some others post instructions :

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0821 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 174f:2408 Syntek 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0483:3748 STMicroelectronics ST-LINK/V2
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

and by trign the `lsb -v -d`  command i get the below result:

```
 lsusb -v -d  0483:3748

Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0483:3748 STMicroelectronics ST-LINK/V2
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0483 STMicroelectronics
  idProduct          0x3748 ST-LINK/V2
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 STMicroelectronics
  iProduct                2 STM32 STLink
  iSerial                 3 &/26MCKN
  bNumConfigsudo journalctl -furations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           39
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           3
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              4 ST Link
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

so can not see the port connection on the Arduino which has been installed by snap as you can see below :

[image]

Also, tried to run Arduino as root user but i get below error:

```
sudo arduino
mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied

(process:22688): dconf-CRITICAL **: 19:29:51.179: unable to create directory '/run/user/0/snap.arduino/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.

(process:22688): dconf-CRITICAL **: 19:29:51.179: unable to create directory '/run/user/0/snap.arduino/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
No protocol specified

(process:22688): dconf-CRITICAL **: 19:29:51.180: unable to create directorit is not worling!.y '/run/user/0/snap.arduino/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: 
Set log4j store directory /root/snap/arduino/56/.arduino15
No protocol specified
java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:102)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment$LocalGE.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment$LocalGE.<clinit>(GraphicsEnvironment.java:83)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:129)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.<clinit>(XToolkit.java:231)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:588)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:583)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:582)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.SystemColor.updateSystemColors(SystemColor.java:473)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.SystemColor.<clinit>(SystemColor.java:465)
    at processing.app.Theme.init(Theme.java:343)
    at processing.app.Base.<init>(Base.java:250)
    at processing.app.Base.main(Base.java:150)
```

So i guess this is not working because of installing the Arduino by snap and trued to fix it by `sudo snap connect arduino:removable-media` command but i get the  `mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied` error again, so i asked here:

**Update1:**

Based of **the first comment** i tried the `sudo journalctl -f`and get **the below results**:

```
sudo journalctl -f
-- Logs begin at Thu 2020-11-19 13:24:37 +0330. --
ژوئن 13 20:24:57 so-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15IKB tunnel.service[4851]: add bridge failed: Operation not permitted
ژوئن 13 20:24:57 so-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15IKB nautilus-deskto[17909]: connect() failed
ژوئن 13 20:24:58 so-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15IKB nautilus-deskto[17909]: connect() failed
ژوئن 13 20:24:59 so-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15IKB nautilus-deskto[17909]: connect() failed
ژوئن 13 20:25:00 so-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15IKB nautilus-deskto[17909]: connect() failed
ژوئن 13 20:25:01 so-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15IKB nautilus-deskto[17909]: connect() failed
ژوئن 13 20:25:02 so-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15IKB nautilus-deskto[17909]: connect() failed
ژوئن 13 20:25:03 so-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15IKB nautilus-deskto[17909]: connect() failed
ژوئن 13 20:25:03 so-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15IKB sudo[30096]:       so : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/so ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -f
ژوئن 13 20:25:03 so-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15IKB sudo[30096]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
ژوئن 13 20:25:04 so-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15IKB nautilus-deskto[17909]: connect() failed
ژوئن 13 20:25:05 so-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15IKB nautilus-deskto[17909]: connect() failed
ژوئن 13 20:25:06 so-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15IKB nautilus-deskto[17909]: connect() failed
ژوئن 13 20:25:07 so-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15IKB tunnel.service[4851]: add bridge failed: Operation not permitted
```

Also i have installed the last Arduino version by [this link](https://www.arduino.cc/en/guide/linux) and is is running by `sudo arduino` command but is til have this problem!.

**Update2:**

It is strange i have seen the [below post](https://dh1tw.de/2020/01/st-link-blue-pill-development-board/) which is saying **the ST-link V2 programmer** could be **fake** and have **some wrong pin connection**, and if possible i like to ask, what would be happening if i change the **2,4,6** pins configuration based of that post? as you can see below:

[image]

**Update 3**:

I have checked the **ST-Link V2** and the pins was labeled correctly. so the problem is not from the wrong **st-link** pins system!.
Thanks.

Comment: Your guesses are wrong. `usermod` changes system files that are only consulted at `login`.

Comment: Your guesses are wrong. Watch `sudo journalctl -f` as you connect the Arduino. It's probably `/dev/ttyUSB*`.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: ST-LInk may not be recognized as ttyUSB and it is normal. You have to find specific guide for setting up ST-Link on Ubuntu. As starting point you can use [this document](https://github.com/stm32duino/wiki/wiki/Upload-methods). For more reproducible results please install Arduino IDE [using ubuntu-make](https://askubuntu.com/a/1025755/66509) and remove snap version (if any).

Answer (score 0):

Based of[N0rbert](https://askubuntu.com/users/66509/n0rbert) Comment,The problem exist by snap version of Arduino which is said [here](https://github.com/stm32duino/wiki/wiki/Upload-methods):

[image]

So I have done the below step:

1- I have installed the last Arduino version by [this link](https://www.arduino.cc/en/guide/linux).

2-Based of [this document](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubeprog.html), I have installed the **STM32CubePrg**

3-Selecting the below setting and codes for test :

[image]

```
#define LED_BUILTIN PC13
void setup() {
  // initialize digital pin LED_BUILTIN as an output.
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}
 
// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(2000);                       // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
}
```

4- Switch the BOOT 0 header from the '0' position to the '1' position before connecting the FTDI board to the computer for flashing the bootloader as said on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uvrT5tfoLGI) from this post:

[image]Thank.